beforesecskip occasionally failing in memoir
I'm typesetting a long and complex book with memoir class. In two cases, \beforesecskip seems to be ignored, in a rather random way which wonders me (I have been using memoir for a couple of years now, and it's the first time I experience such an issue).
Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this behavior in a MWE. I use common packages for indexes, and bibleref-parse for bible citations; moreover, two series of footnotes with memoir's mechanism. But I don't see how they can affect such a simple thing as a section skip...
If I do \show\section just before the problematic section, I read
\section=\long macro:
->\sechook \@startsection {section}{1}
{\secindent }{\beforesecskip }{\aftersecskip }
{\normalfont \secheadstyle }.

which seems to be the standard memoir definition. And \the\beforesecskip correctly prints my value (-17.80016pt). My \sechook is \setsecnumformat {\csname the##1\endcsname .\ }.
Still, I get this output, without skip:

(corresponding snippet of code, just to give an idea:
...«Ahora, habiendo sido vosotros liberados del pecado y hechos siervos de Dios, poseéis como fruto la santidad y, al final, la vida eterna».

\section{Gracia y misión}
El servicio a su destinación original encargada por Dios, la de amar a Dios y al prójimo, fundamenta el estado del hombre sin más como «\textemph{estado de gracia}»,...

)
So, two questions:

Can memoir's beforesecskip have some elasticity even if it's defined as a fixed value, without plus nor minus?

Some hints how to proceed in order to debug?



As long as others cannot recreate it, or you haven't provided a setup others can copy and test, there is not much we can do.
